# Is there a way to add scroll bars to the bottom and right window in a processing sketch?

Tags: java, scroll, processing, scrollbar

I am looking to add scroll bars to a window in processing that will allow a user to scroll along the x or y axis to view a graph that is too large for a window.  I did create a class that works somewhat for vertical scrolling, but it is only moving down and not back up. Below is my class and subset of code:

```
class ScrollRect {

  float rectPosX=0;
  float rectPosY=0;
  float rectWidth=14; 
  float rectHeight=30;

  boolean holdScrollRect=false; 

  float offsetMouseY; 

  //constr
  ScrollRect() {
    // you have to make a scrollRect in setup after size()
    rectPosX=width-rectWidth-1;
  }//constr

  void display() {
    fill(122);
    stroke(0);
    line (rectPosX-1, 0, 
      rectPosX-1, height);
    rect(rectPosX, rectPosY, 
      rectWidth, rectHeight);

    // Three small lines in the center   
    centerLine(-3); 
    centerLine(0);
    centerLine(3);
  }

  void centerLine(float offset) {
    line(rectPosX+3, rectPosY+rectHeight/2+offset, 
      rectPosX+rectWidth-3, rectPosY+rectHeight/2+offset);
  }

  void mousePressedRect() {
    if (mouseOver()) {
      holdScrollRect=true;
      offsetMouseY=mouseY-rectPosY;
    }
  }

  void mouseReleasedRect() {
    scrollRect.holdScrollRect=false;
  }

  void update() {
    // dragging of the mouse 
    if (holdScrollRect) {
      rectPosY=mouseY-offsetMouseY;
      if (rectPosY<0)
        rectPosY=0;
      if (rectPosY+rectHeight>height-1)
        rectPosY=height-rectHeight-1;
    }
  }

  float scrollValue() {
    return
      map(rectPosY, 
      0, height-rectHeight, 
      0, - (heightOfCanvas - height));
  }

  boolean mouseOver() {
    return mouseX>rectPosX&&
      mouseX<rectPosX+rectWidth&&
      mouseY>rectPosY&&
      mouseY<rectPosY+rectHeight;
  }//function 
  //
}//class 
//
```

What I have so far:

```
void draw() {
    pushMatrix();

  // reading scroll bar 
  float newYValue = scrollRect.scrollValue();  
  translate (0, newYValue);

  //allows zoom
  scale(max(0.01, zoom));
  // background color
  background(#F0F8FF);
//sets scrolling

  scrollRect.display();
  scrollRect.update();
  // plot area  
  fill(#FFFFFF);
  rectMode(CORNERS);
  noStroke();
  rect(plotX1, plotY1, plotX2, plotY2);


  drawTitleTabs();
  drawAxisLabels();
  drawVolumeLabels();

  // data area color
  fill(#009900);
  drawDataArea(currentColumn);

  drawXTickMarks();
  // rollover color
  stroke(#5679C1);
  noFill();
  strokeWeight(2);
  drawDataHighlight(currentColumn);

  // legend
  textSize(16);
  fill(#000000);
  textAlign(LEFT);
  text("somthing.", legendX, legendY);

   popMatrix();
}
```

Comment: Sis you know about [Processing's HScrollbar class](https://processing.org/examples/scrollbar.html) ? You may be closer to achieve this that you think.

Answer (score 0):

You can use mouseWheel function it will simply give you 1 for scrolling up and -1 for scrolling down.
Check it out in the processing reference.

```
here is the link too: https://processing.org/reference/mouseWheel_.html
```